# Irreducible Representation of A_5

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, modular-representation-theory, induced-representations

Knowing the fact that standard representation arising out of permutation representation of $A_5$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is irreducible and of degree $4$. What can we conclude about the irreducibility over general field, whose characteristics does not divide the order of $A_5$. Is it irreducible ? Can we use Clifford Theory here ? How ?

Comment: You write "whose characteristic does NOT divide the order", is that a typo? I'm asking since you also added the "modular representation theory" tag. Typically modular representation theory refers to the case where the characteristic divides the group order. In characteristic not dividing the group order, the representation theory behaves as in characteristic zero, in particular your representation is irreducible.

Comment: @AchimKrause I am actually asking the semi simple casein my question and you have answered my question, so Thanks . Can you refer me some article to support your argument that charactersitic zero and my case behave in same way. How ?

Comment: The standard argument on how to decompose the permutation character of a 2-transitive action can be made to work for representations in good characteristic of you reinterpret the character arguments as computing dimensions of him spaces.  You will want to use that a permutation representation is equivalent to its contragredient.

Comment: In other words the argument that the dimension of the endomorphism algebra of a permutation module equals the number of orbits on pairs can be carried out in nonmodular characteristic without using characters by looking at hom set dimensions and then the result follows from there.

Comment: @Benjamin Actually I am not familiar with the concepts you mentioned. Can I prove the irreducibilty of FA_5 module V (where V is standard permutation module) for the field of given characteristic not dividing order of A_5? by using module theory arguments, as we can prove in case of S_5 by using the transposition (12) ( which is not here ) .

Comment: I'm suggesting a conceptual way to do this using permutation modules and centralizer algebras or endomorphism rings that would work for An for n\geq 4 and S_n. If you want just A5 by bare hands I think math stack exchange is a more appropriate site.

Comment: @Benjamin Please refer some book to me , where I can read these concepts and arrive at the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122714/discussion-between-himanshu-setia-and-benjamin-steinberg).

Comment: You can find all these concepts in Isaac's character theory book

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg In Issac's character theory book, they are taking the field of complex numbers to define permutation module. Why will the same reasoning be valid in  non-modular case ?

Comment: As a general comment, Clifford theory is only useful in the representation theory of finite groups in the presence of proper non-trivial normal subgroups., so is not so relevant for simple groups.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Clifford theory could be relevant if the problem was somehow easier for $S_5$.

Comment: The definition of the permutation module is the same over any field and he does endomorphism rings equal centralizer rings.  The argument @GeoffRobinson gives in characteristic zero works in any non modular characteristic.

Comment: For the specific example of $A_5$, the result remains true in characteristics $2$ and $3$, but not $5$. (It is never true when the characteristic divides the degree of the permutation representation.)

Comment: I am voting to reopen, mainly because Geoff has devoted some effort into answering this and related questions.

Comment: @DerekHolt: You are probably aware of this, but closing the question is not the same as deleting it: Geoff's work would not go away if the question were closed. Imo whether a question should be closed has to do with whether it is on-topic, not whether it has nice answers (which this one does).

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes I can see that this question is a doubtful case! But I believe that closed questions are not so universally  visible as others. Apparently a closed question is "viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege".

Answer (score 6):

Here is a fairly general answer for the characteristic zero question you ask, which I will mark as Community Wiki:

Let $G$ be any doubly transitive permutation group of degree $n$ on a set $\Omega$. Let $V$ be the underlying  permutation module, viewed as the $\mathbb{Q}G$-module $\mathbb{Q}\Omega$. Then $V \cong U \oplus W$, where $U$ is the trivial $\mathbb{Q}G$-module and $W$ is $n-1$-dimensional ($U$ may be realised as the space of $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combinations of elements of $\Omega$ with all coefficients equal, and $W$ is the set of all $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combinations of elements of $\Omega$ in which the sum of coefficients appearing is zero.

It is an easy exercise that ${\rm End}_{\mathbb{Q}G}(W) \cong \mathbb{Q}$ (this uses the double transitivity of the permutation action).  This implies that the representation afforded by $W$ is absolutely irreducible- that is, remains irreducible after any extension of scalars enlarging $\mathbb{Q}$ to any extension field. Since any field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristic zero has prime subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, we see
that $W \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{F}$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{F}G$-module.

( This is, of course, all standard theory)

Later edit: In view of some of the comments, let me point out that this argument does not always generalize to prime characteristic dividing the group order. Possibly The easiest case it fails is when the prime characteristic $p$ is a divisor of $n$, the degree of the permutation representation, a case mentioned by Derek Holt in comments.

For if $\mathbb{F}$ is a field of prime characteristic $p$ which divides
$n = |\Omega|$, then the permutation module $\mathbb{F}\Omega$ has two obvious submodules $U$ and $W$ defined as before, but note that $U \subseteq W$ in this case because the coefficients appearing in any element of  $U$ sum to zero. Hence $W$ is not irreducible (if $n >2$ to discount a trivial exception). We also find that $\mathbb{F}\Omega/W \cong U$. Hence the permutation module $\mathbb{F}\Omega$ has at least three composition factors, at least two of which are trivial. The $n-2$-dimensional module $W/U$ is sometimes called the Green heart (after J.A. Green). It is often irreducible, but I think examples exist when it is not.

Comment: This all works in any characteristic that doesn’t divide the order of the group with the easy exercise being only a tiny bit less easy.  The centralizer algebra of the permutation module has basis the characteristic matrices of orbitals (orbits on pairs).

Comment: @DerekHolt, I think this only works when $p$ doesn't divide the order of the group.  2 divides the order of PSL_3(2).

Comment: @DerekHolt, are you sure that it is a direct sum rather than a composition series?

Comment: @DerekHolt, it would seem to me the centralizer algebra still has dimension 2 but if what such a direct sum it would be 3.  But an indecomposable can have centralizer algebra of dimension 1 and still have two constituents,

Comment: On the contrary, I am sure it is not! Let me start again. For a counterexample when $p$ divides $|G|$, consider the permutation representation of ${\rm SL}_3(2)$ on $7$ points, which is doubly transitive. This decomposes as $T \oplus V$ with $T$ the trivial module and $V$ indecomposable of dimension $6$, but $V$ is not irreducible - it has two mutually dual composition factors, each of dimension $3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I believe the usual argument for irreducibility over C shows in characteristic not dividing the degree of the 2-transitive permutation representation the permutation module decomposes as the direct sum of the trivial module and an absolutely indecomposable module. So in nonmodular characteristic you get what the op wants

Comment: @Geoff Thanks for so much efforts in answering. Actually the concepts of double transitivity of permutation groups and absolute irreducibility were new for me yesterday. But now, I have understood the journey from double transitivity to irreducibility by using character theory and also without using it( in non-modular cases ) with the help of stablizers. Thanks Benjamin, Derek, lambda, Achim for your time and energy.